# How to increase contrast between colors generated from image?

Tags: image-processing, colors, color-picker, color-palette, framerjs

### Some details:

I'm making a small prototype in Framer, some kind a wallpaper app. I use **vibrant.js** to automatically pick colors from the images to add a bit of a tint to my interface. I use two vibrant color profiles: "DarkMuted" - for the backgrounds and "Vibrant" - for active controls / accents etc.

Unfortunately, color combintation looks dull and desaturated sometimes, active elements don't stand out as much as I want it. 
So my first decision was to

### **Blindly edit colors**.

I convert them to `hsl` and explicitly set `s` and `l` values.

```
s: .2, l: .2  #  DarkMuted

s: .6, l: .8  #  Vibrant
```

This **creates enough** contrast between the two, but also has a drawback: sometimes colors look a bit **oversaturated and distorted** (compared to the input).

[By this link](https://www.dropbox.com/home/examples) you can find pairs of screenshots to show you the difference between "original" color pair returned by "vibrant.js" and colors with adjusted s and l values.

I've already [asked](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105689/adjusting-generated-colors-to-make-them-more-subjectively-pleasant) on another forum if it's possible to apply automated adjustments to the color, to **normalize percieved bias** for some color ranges. The answer was **"almost impossible"**.

I would say that subjectively **acceptable color rate** is ~ 65% but the result is **too unpredictable**. Since it's an automatic solution I **can't rely** on that too much.

So I decided to approach it another way:

### Generate a bunch of colors and filter one

The problem here is:

I've not found how to generate **more than one color per profile** with vibrant.js

Also, I've tried the **color-thief.js** library to generate a palette of dominant colors and then filter, what I call, a "vibrant" color.

```
# Threshold values I used 
thr = {minL: .4, maxL: .8, minS: .6, maxS: .8}
```

But here the another problem occurs - not every image has a set of colors that fall under my threshold. Some images have a pastel gamma or b/w and **don't return anything**.

So,

- Can I **overcome** the vibrant.js limitation of **1 color per profile** to have a bunch of "Vibrant" colors and then pick one that suits my requirements?
- Or, maybe, there is **another / better solution** of doing it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a specification about minimum contrast between colors (WCAG) you can find it [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum.html). So a possible strategie would be extracting the colors with vibrant.js and after that you could check contrast with a function. You can find a guide to build a function to check color constrast [here](https://medium.com/tamman-inc/create-your-own-color-contrast-checker-11d8b95dff5b). The last step probably would be generate colors variations with good contrast based on the results from the color contrast function. You can generate variations using [this lib](https://github.com/surfacecurve/sc-color).